# Angular CTRL + S to submit form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

How can i add a global listener that invoke submit button in all application forms

When the user press `ctrl+s`

I Use Template forms and all the froms are ngForm

I Want to realize something like this: (without jQuery)

```
$("#container form").submit();
```

Comment: Are you using Reactive Forms? How should your application know about all the forms? How should your application know about the submit buttons? These are questions which we can't solve for you, it highly depends on your implementations. After finding solutions for that questions, it should be trivial to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'form'
})
export class SaveCtrlSDirective {

    constructor(private ngForm: NgForm) { }

    @HostListener('document:keydown.control.s', ['$event'])  
    onKeydownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        (this.ngForm as {submitted: boolean}).submitted = true;
        this.ngForm.ngSubmit.emit(this.ngForm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register following event globally.
Based on what form you are currently on, trigger submitting ( formSubmit / trigger button click method )

```js
    document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
      if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 's') {
        // Stop app to open save window
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('CTRL + S Clicked');
        // do your form submission logic here
      }
    });
```

Comment: This is a good plain JavaScript solution, however in an Angular component this can be done better

Answer (score 1):

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.control.s', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: 
KeyboardEvent) {
   console.log('Submitted');
   event.preventDefault();
   // todo
}
```

Comment: It explains how can i add listener, but does not give information on how to invoke submit button

Comment: Hostlistener itself has no way to know that you actually want to fire submit event on some random form when you press ctrl + s. In angular, you dont mess around DOM directly, so to achieve that desired behaviour globally you need to add custom directive to each form, which would get the reference to currently used form in `ctrl +s hostlistener` and programmatically invoke `submit`. Check this article: https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20190215-ProgrammaticSubmitForAngularHostListener.html